# Time Machine Backup Drive Shows Empty Files

Tags: backup, time-machine, external-disk

I have backed up my MacBook using Time Machine to an external hard drive. Now, when I try to open it on a Mac Mini, it doesn't detect my .backupdb files. I were able to see some of the .backupdb file previously, but now they are gone.

Note:

1. I believe the files are still there since it's still occupying 100GB+ of my external hard drive.
2. I have checked the permissions of the hard drive and it's read and write.
3. 'Browse Other Backup Disks' list is empty

Is there any way to see my files on the backup drive?

Thank you

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by 'it doesn't detect my .backupdb files'? (They should be folders in any case.) You mean they are not visible in the Finder? Have you tried showing invisible files?

Comment: @benwiggy, yes they are not visible in the finder. I have also tried to show invisible files.

Comment: Do you still have the MacBook? Do they show there?

Comment: @benwiggy Unfortunately I do not have the MacBook anymore, I believe it was showing there.

Comment: What was the version of macOS on the MacBook? And what is the version of macOS on the Mac Mini?

Comment: I have the same problem, and to me they seem to be happening in the same device, too. I wiped my disk and backed up completely, but the drive is still empty and I'm not getting the "backup completed" message.